# Git clone using https is not working, but works with help of ssh

Tags: git, clone

Git clone using https is not working on my mac machine, getting following error :

```
akshaybandivadekar@Akshays-MacBook-Pro codebase % git clone https://github.com/lodash/lodash.git
Cloning into 'lodash'...
akshaybandivadekar@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But using ssh it works

```
git clone git@github.com:lodash/lodash.git
```

I have referred this document for ssh key setup:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolve my problem

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```